# Rename all folders with owner name script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rename, owner

Im trying to change the name of folders inside a folder to the name of the folders owner..
Exemple, I have a folder with one hundred other folder's all with the name "My Documents" and all of the with a diferente owner.
I already find a way to find the name with the code:
dir /q
but I have no ideia on how to put it in a variable and use that variable to change the folders name...

Comment: You can use something like `for /F "tokens=4" %%O in ('dir /A:D /Q') do (echo %%O)` to get the owner, supposing it does not contain white-spaces -- type `for /?` into command prompt and read the help text carefully... note that the output of `dir` depends on the locale and region settings of the system...

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to get a commands output is a `for`.

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=2 tokens=4,*" %%a in ('dir /q /ad^|find "<DIR>"') do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=\" %%i in ("%%a") do (
    echo owner=%%i
    echo folder=%%b
    echo ren "%%b" "%%i"
  )
)
```

Comment: That appears to work (no errors on cmd) but the files simply dont change... :\

Comment: it is usus on this site to "unarm" potentially dangerous code. Remove the `echo` in front of `ren` when you verified that the output is ok.

Comment: hmm now it get "Sintax is incorrect"  because its using the name as "domain\user" ... can I remove everything before the"\"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a batch script -- let us call it `rename-dir-by-owner.bat` -- based on the code in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302887/rename-all-folders-with-owner-name-script#comment62128488_37302887):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%U in ('
    dir /Q /A:D "%~1" ^| find "<DIR>" ^| findstr /V /R /C:" \.*\.$"
') do (
    set "ITEM=%%U"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "ITEM=!ITEM:*<DIR>=!" & set "ITEM=!ITEM:*\=!"
    for /F "tokens=1,* delims= " %%O in ("!ITEM!") do (
        endlocal
        ECHO ren "%~dp1%%P" "%%O"
        setlocal
    )
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

To use this script, provide the directory containing the ones subject to rename as a command line argument -- like this, for instance, supposing the directory is called `parent-folder`:

```
rename-dir-by-owner.bat "parent-folder"
```

The upper-case `ECHO` command is there for testing purposes; remove it as soon as you actually want to rename any items.

---

#### Explanation

The output of the core `dir /Q /A:D` command line used in the above script looks similar to this:

> ```
>  Volume in drive D has no label.
>  Volume Serial Number is XXXX-XXXX
>
>  Directory of D:\Data
>
> 2016/01/01  00:00    <DIR>          NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM    .
> 2016/01/01  00:00    <DIR>          BUILTIN\Administrators ..
> 2015/07/01  01:00    <JUNCTION>     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM    AppData [C:\Users\aschipfl\AppData\Roaming]
> 2016/03/21  20:00    <DIR>          HOST\aschipfl          Documents
> 2016/05/18  23:00    <DIR>          HOST\aschipfl          Drawings
> 2016/04/01  13:00    <DIR>          HOST\aschipfl          Projects
>                0 File(s)              0 bytes
>                6 Dir(s)   2'147'483'648 bytes free
> ```

The `find` command filters out all lines that do not contain `<DIR>` (which marks directories), `findstr` removes the dummy directories `.` (current) and `..` (parent). So the following lines remain:

> ```
> 2016/03/21  20:00    <DIR>          HOST\aschipfl          Documents
> 2016/05/18  23:00    <DIR>          HOST\aschipfl          Drawings
> 2016/04/01  13:00    <DIR>          HOST\aschipfl          Projects
> ```

These lines are captured by the outer `for /F` loop, each one is stored in variable `ITEM`. Afterwards everything up to the portion `<DIR>` is removed, then everything up to the (first) `\` is cut off. The remaining content of `ITEM` is now parsed with another `for /F` loop, which extracts everything in front of the first white-spaces, so the user name of the owner is retrieved; behind the white-spaces is the directory name. Both string parts are passed over to the `ren` command finally (once `ECHO` is away).

With this approach the result does (almost) not depend on the locale and region settings of the system, so a quite general solution is achieved. However, this batch program leads to unexpected results if a user name contains white-spaces, but such is not recommended by Microsoft anyway -- consult this article: [Creating User and Group Accounts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726984.aspx), section "Rules for Logon Names".